# Global Ajax Event Handler to handler ASP.Net Web-API 401

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

ASP.Net Web-API 2, by default, returns a "304 found" redirect when a request fails authorization. This isn't useful for an ajax request, so I'm using the "X-Responded-JSON" response header to check for the actual 401 response, and then redirect the user from javascript back to the correct login URL. Like so...

```
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var json_response = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("X-Responded-JSON");
    if (json_response) {
       var json_response_obj = JSON.parse(json_response);
       if (json_response_obj.status == 401) {
          if (confirm("You are not authorised. Would you like to login again?"))
             location.href = login_url; //my MVC login URL
             return;
          }
       }
    }
    alert('all done');
    //do other stuff
```

This works fine. However when I've got a number of ajax calls on a page, it seems a little clumsy. Obviously I could put it all in a function, however I still need to remember to call it for every ajax call I might add.

What I'm wondering is if there's some way to add a global ajax handler, in which I could place my login redirect code, and ensure that it will be executed before the done method is called for the individual ajax request. So I could simply write my ajax request as normal...

```
.done(function (data) {
   alert('all done');
   //do other stuff
}
```

The global handler would ensure that the 401 is correctly processed.

The issue is that .ajaxComplete() executes after .done, so my ajax code would incorrectly advise the user that the request has been successfully processed, when in fact it hasn't.

Does anyone know if there is a way to setup a global ajax handler which will execute before .done?